# Compatibility Issue of Laravel 9 PHP 8.0.2 and Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I worked with PHP version 8.1, and I downgraded the version to 8.0.2.

**I don't want to update the version of PHP.**

My version now of Laravel, PHP, Composer:

```
Laravel version: ^9
PHP version: 8.0.2
Composer version: 2.3.10
```

I try to run the project and see these errors:

Error in the browser to try to run the project:

`Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.2. in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn_laravel\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on line 24`

The error of trying to install `composer i`:

```
Problem 1
    - symfony/console is locked to version v6.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/console v6.1.2 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/css-selector is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/css-selector v6.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - symfony/deprecation-contracts is locked to version v3.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/deprecation-contracts v3.1.1 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - symfony/error-handler is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/error-handler v6.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - symfony/event-dispatcher is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/event-dispatcher v6.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts is locked to version v3.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v3.1.1 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - symfony/finder is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/finder v6.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - symfony/http-foundation is locked to version v6.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/http-foundation v6.1.2 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - symfony/http-kernel is locked to version v6.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/http-kernel v6.1.2 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - symfony/mailer is locked to version v6.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/mailer v6.1.2 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 11
    - symfony/mime is locked to version v6.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/mime v6.1.1 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 12
    - symfony/process is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/process v6.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 13
    - symfony/routing is locked to version v6.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/routing v6.1.1 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 14
    - symfony/service-contracts is locked to version v3.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/service-contracts v3.1.1 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 15
    - symfony/string is locked to version v6.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/string v6.1.2 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 16
    - symfony/translation is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/translation v6.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 17
    - symfony/translation-contracts is locked to version v3.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/translation-contracts v3.1.1 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 18
    - symfony/var-dumper is locked to version v6.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/var-dumper v6.1.0 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 19
    - symfony/http-foundation v6.1.2 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - spatie/flare-client-php 1.2.0 requires symfony/http-foundation ^5.0|^6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v6.1.2].
    - spatie/flare-client-php is locked to version 1.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Comment: in "composer.json" define php dependency like: `"php": "^7.4|^8.0"`. But if your Laravel version is not compatible with php version, you have to update php or lower your laravel version.

Comment: The truth is I deleted the `composer.json` file and run `composer i` and it worked,
Thanks for any case

Comment: because your composer reinstalled itself. And most probably it is already done what I have said. Glad to help

Comment: I also think thank you very much!

Comment: PHP 8.0.2 is pretty outdated - why not use the most recent version of PHP 8.0? Also, removing `composer.json` won't resolve any problem, but only cause new ones.

Comment: The most recent version that can be used in AWS is 8.0.2. And the truth is that it solved my problem.

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-php.html, it should not be too hard to use a later PHP version